# Как выделить слова в строке?

Tags: c, строки, выделение-текста

Как в строках st1 и st2 выделить sl1 и sl2? выделить скобками или звездочками с двух сторон. Например, (Мама) мыла раму ---->  (Папа) мыла раму

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #define N 256
    void smal(char* str)
    {
        while (*str)
        {
            *str = tolower(*str);
            str++;
        }
    }
    int let(char letter) {
        char b = tolower(letter);
        char a[] = "ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю";
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == b)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
     /*если j > 0 и j - 1 символ это буква то не делаем замену.
        если j + x символ это буква то замену не делаем.*/

    int proverka(char st1[], char sl[], int index)
    {
        if (index > 0 && let(st1[index - 1]))   return 0;// Если в строке есть предыдущие символы и это буква, выходим
        int len = 0;
        for (int i = 0; sl[i] && st1[index + i]; i++) 
        {
            if (sl[i] != st1[index + i])
            return 0;
            len++;               // подсчитывает длину слова
        }
        // если дошли сюда, то проверяет символ st1[index + len]
        // если он не буква, то возвращает длину строки
        return (!let(st1[index + len])) ? len : 0;
    }
    void zamena(char st1[], char sl1[], char sl2[], char st2[])
    {
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; st1[i]; i++)
    {
        int len = proverka(st1, sl1, i);
        if (len)  //если нашли нужное слово
        {
            i += len;  //в len у нас длина стоки slovo1, которую мы перепрыгиваем
            for (int j = 0; sl2[j]; j++) 
            st2[pos++] = sl2[j];  //на место стоки slovo1 ставим slovo2
        }
        else 
        {
            st2[pos++] = st1[i];   //просто копируем символ
        }
        st2[pos] = NULL;  //ставим конец строки
    }

    }

    int main()
        {
        int g;
        do
        {
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
            printf("Введите строку:");
            char st1[255] = { 0 };
            SetConsoleCP(1251);
            gets_s(st1);
            SetConsoleCP(866);
            printf("Ваша строка:%s", st1);
            getchar();
            smal(st1);
            printf("Введите слово, которое заменить:");
            char sl1[255] = { 0 };
            SetConsoleCP(1251);
            gets_s(sl1);
            SetConsoleCP(866);
            printf("Слово,которое хотите заменить:%s", sl1);
            getchar();
            smal(sl1);
            printf("Введите слово,на которое заменить:");
            char sl2[255] = { 0 };
            SetConsoleCP(1251);
            gets_s(sl2);
            SetConsoleCP(866);
            printf("Слово,на которое заменить:%s", sl2);
            getchar();
            char st2[200];
            zamena(st1, sl1, sl2, st2);
            printf("\n Исходная строка:%s", st1);
            printf("\n Измененная строка:%s", st2);
            printf("\n1-Продолжить:");
            scanf("%d", &g);
            getchar();
        } 
        while (g == 1);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Используйте строковые функции и методы языка.
Например, почитайте тут: http://cppstudio.com/post/437/

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вызвать функцию zamena два раза:

```
zamena("Мама мыла раму", "Мама", "(Мама)", res1[]);
zamena("Мама мыла раму", "Мама", "(Папа)", res2[]);
```

ну и делать с res1 и res2 все что захочется

Посмотрел функцию zamena.

Есть смысл заменить функцию let(...)  на стандартную функцию std::isalpha, которая возвращает true, если символ является буквой верхнего или нижнего регистра. Или, если хочется самому написать, вспомнить про таблицу ASCII -- если letter лежит внутри диапазона ['а', 'я'] - то это буква нижнего регистра.

Ну и

```
       st2[pos] = NULL;  //ставим конец строки
```

Зачем лежит в цикле? Его можно вынести и ничего не изменится.